# Limiting users ram with cgroups not working (for me)

Tags: ubuntu, systemd, limit, ram, cgroups

I registred because I didn't manage running cgroups with several tutorials/comments/whatever you find on google. I want to limit the amount of ram a specifix user may use. Internet says "cgroups". My testserver is running Ubuntu 14.04. You can divide the mentioned tutorials in two categories. Directly set limits using echo and use specific config. Neither is working for me.

**Setting Limits using echo**

```
cgcreate -g cpu,cpuacct,...:/my_group
```

finishes without any notices. When I try to run

```
echo 100M > memory.limit_in_bytes
```

it just says "not permitted" even when using sudo. I don't even reach any point of limiting another user.

**Setting limits using config**

I read about two config files. So here are my config files:

*cgconfig.conf*

```
mount {
    memory  = /cgroup/memory;
}

group limit_grp {
        memory {
                memory.limit_in_bytes=100M;
                memory.memsw.limit_in_bytes=125M;
        }
}
```

*cgrules.conf*

```
testuser    memory    limit_grp
```

When I run

```
cgconfigparser -l /etc/cgconfig.conf
```

it mounts to systemd. Now I log on with testuser, run an memory intense task - and it runs without caring about my limit.

I tried rebooting, nothing changed. Even some strange attempts using kernel config didn't work. I'm new to cgroups and didn't expect it to be that complicated. I'd appreciate any suggestions to my topic. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Could you be more specific when you say "mounts to systemd"? You mentioned this was on Ubuntu 14.04, which is not running systemd (but has some related patches).

Comment: It's easy to misunderstand (and hence misapply) redirection with `sudo`, too.

Comment: I can either add cgroups to /etc/fstab (which will lead to 'failed to parse config') or don't add it at first and pase config. Both fstab and parsing lead to following output in mount: "systemd on /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd type cgroup (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,none,name=systemd)"

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're seeing this behaviour is probably due to the fact that your login session already has a memory limit group associated, and the process is inheriting that, according to systemd configuration.

Check your running process cgroup with:

```
cat /proc/pid/cgroup
```

...and you may see something like:

```
13:name=systemd:/user/0.user/2.session
12:debug:/
11:pids:/
10:net_prio:/user/0.user/2.session
9:perf_event:/user/0.user/2.session
8:net_cls:/user/0.user/2.session
7:freezer:/user/0.user/2.session
6:devices:/user/0.user/2.session
5:memory:/user/0.user/2.session
4:blkio:/user/0.user/2.session
3:cpuacct:/user/0.user/2.session
2:cpu:/
1:cpuset:/
```

Assuming you don't want this behavior, you can use your custom cgroup with memory controller editing `/etc/systemd/logind.conf` and removing `memory` from the `Controllers` line.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem (on Fedora 29, though): It seemed that my `/etc/cgconfig.conf` was completely ignored. Running

```
sudo systemctl enable cgconfig
```

and rebooting solved the problem.